# Prevent Android webView rotation

Tags: java, android, webview, rotation

I have a webview on my activity and I want to be able to control its rotation behaviour. According to [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

> The standard behavior for an Activity is to be destroyed and recreated when the device orientation or any other configuration changes. This will cause the WebView to reload the current page. If you don't want that, you can set your Activity to handle the orientation and keyboardHidden changes, and then just leave the WebView alone. It'll automatically re-orient itself as appropriate. Read Handling Runtime Changes for more information about how to handle configuration changes during runtime.

So,that "*It'll automatically re-orient itself as appropriate"* is what I want to control.

Comment: Are you wanting to keep the whole app from rotating?

Comment: No, that is the point. Only the webview

Comment: are there anyother views on your activity or just webview

Comment: just the webview but the main app have to keep rotating regardless the webview setting

Answer (score 0):

If you need to stop the rotation of webview, then You can set the orientation in manifest only for the activity which holds the webview.